# how can I detect thick lines in python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I'm trying to detect a tennis court line, from a side angle, my input and output images are:

[image: images:]

the one with the green lines is the output.
as you can see, the output image is partly correct, but i need all of the white line or even better if possible just the edges of the line, my code is:

```py
import cv2
import imutils
import numpy as np

#read image
image = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\talcl\PycharmProjects\VisionLine\project\library\image_18.jpeg")
image = imutils.resize(image, width=600)
image = image[300:800, 200:500]
cv2.imshow('input', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#performing binary thresholding
kernel_size = 3
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

#finding contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

#drawing Contours
radius =2
color = (30,255,50)
cv2.drawContours(image, cnts, -1,color , radius)
# cv2.imshow(image) commented as colab don't support cv2.imshow()
cv2.imshow('frame', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I will be grateful for every suggestion you have, thanks!

I tried to detect the thick white line, i expected the code to color all of it but it colored only few parts of it. Another possible output is just the edges of the line

Comment: I think you have to change properties of your threshold.

Comment: Check out canny edge detection. It will give you the edges of the court lines. Here: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html

Comment: You don’t want to use Canny here. It is not intended to provide closed contours. This is a trivial problem. A simple Otsu threshold should find the right threshold value.

Comment: Please show original image, not a screen snap of your application.